# Why does changing how a child object is looked up auto-validate said child object through it's parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Suppose you have the classes `Client` and `Phone`. A `Client` `has_one` `Phone`, and a `Phone` `belongs_to` a `Client`.

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account

  has_one :default_phone, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Phone"
end

class Phone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :account

  validates :number,
            format: { with: /\A\d{4,13}\z/ } # at least 4 digits
end
```

I find that when assigning attributes to a `Phone` object with invalid values, depending on how said child `Phone` object variable is defined it may or may not render the parent `Client` object invalid.

For example, when defining `@default_phone` directly as the client's phone in `#default_phone`, this will render the `Client` parent object invalid after assigning invalid attributes to `@default_phone`:

```
@client = Client.find(1)
@account = @client.account

@fname = "Test"

def client_params
  {
    fname: @fname
  }
end
  
@number = "55" ## invalid. Minimum 4 digits

def default_phone_params
  {
    id: default_phone&.id,
    account_id: @client.account.id,
    number: @number
  }
end
  
def default_phone
  @default_phone ||= @client.default_phone&.presence
end

@client.assign_attributes(client_params)
@client.invalid?
#=> false

default_phone&.assign_attributes(default_phone_params)
@client.invalid?
#=> true
@client.errors.keys
#=> [:"default_phone.number"]
```

Instead, if `@default_phone` is defined by looking up a `Phone` object by it's `id`, this does not happen.
Same example as above but changing how `@default_phone` is defined in `#default_phone`:

```
@client = Client.find(1)
@account = @client.account

@fname = "Test"

def client_params
  {
    fname: @fname
  }
end
  
@number = "55" ## invalid. Minimum 4 digits

def default_phone_params
  {
    id: default_phone&.id,
    account_id: @client.account.id,
    number: @number
  }
end
  
def default_phone
  @default_phone ||= @account.phones.find(@client.default_phone.id)
end


@client.assign_attributes(client_params)
default_phone&.assign_attributes(default_phone_params)

@client.invalid?
#=> false

default_phone.invalid?
#=> true
default_phone.errors.keys
#=> :number
```

Why does assigning invalid attributes to `@default_phone` render the `@client` object invalid in the first example but not in the second?

I'd expect `@client` to be invalid if it's child `Phone` object attributes were assigned through nested attributes in `client_params` for example, but this is not the case as `@default_phone` is being assigned attributes independantly.  Still, the `@client` error key is `default_phone.number`.

Also, `validates_associated :default_phone` is not defined in the `Client` class either.

I've tried setting `autosave: false` on the `Client` `default_phone` association, to the same effects.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Couple of questions: why does client belong_to client? Also, what is the full error when the client is invalid?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. When the client is invalid the error key is default_phone.number (association_name.invalid_attribute).